# Error defining an object type to hold data for an imported DynamoDB table when trying to create a new AppSync Datasource

Tags: graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

In my already existing DynamoDB table I have (in plain JSON, for visualization)

```
{
 "id": 1,
 "data": [
  {
   "battery_level": 87,
   "coordinates": {
    "hash": "qtb6ed22c",
    "lat_lng": [
     -12.20429,
     113.00578
    ]
   },
   "timestamp": 1689082353
  }
 ]
}
```

I am trying to create a new datasource for my GraphQL API in the AWS AppSync console. I want to automatically generate GraphQL to extend my existing schema and automatically configure resolvers. In the top editor that appears after turning on ***Automatically generate GraphQL*** I specify:

```
type TrackerModule {
  # Key attributes. Changing these may result in unexpected behavior.
  id: Int!

  # Add additional non-key attributes below.
  name: String
  data: [TrackerModuleData!]!
}

type TrackerModuleData {
  battery_level: Int!
  coordinates: Coordinates!
  timestamp: Int!
}

type Coordinates {
  hash: String!
  lat_lng: [Float!]!
}
```

However when I then try to create the data source I get an error

> Error: Type "TrackerModuleData" not found in document

I can't figure out what is wrong with my specified GraphQL